# background-attachment: local; CSS style not working in Firefox

Tags: css, background-attachment

I am trying to show a line number for every line. My code working properly in Chrome but in Firefox it's not working because of background-attachment: local; not accepting in Firefox. I want it should work in both browsers.

**JsFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/k8go4d5b/

**Here is my code:**

```css
textarea{
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/2cOaJ.png);
  background-attachment: local;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
```

Comment: Your fiddle worked for me on Firefox... which FF version are you using? check here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-attachment

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same issue with Firefox version 124.0 (64bit) on Windows.  This is the latest released version at the time of writing.

This is indeed a bug in Firefox when applying `background-attachment: local;` to a `textarea` element.

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1007064

This bug was reported/opened more than 10 years ago.   It's mind-blowing that it has not been fixed in all that time.

I have not found any workarounds.

Comment: @DarkBee  Thanks for your guidance.  However, I believe it is quite clear that my response is not a question.  It is an answer - of sorts.  The existing answer and comment did nothing to confirm to the OP that others can replicate the issue.  Nor did they inform the OP that there is a known and open Firefox bug report for the issue, with no stated workaround.  I believe pointing this out to the OP, and others, qualifies as an answer.

Comment: @DarkBee  I am seeing the same issue in my own code, in the OP's example and in both the examples linked in the bug report.  That is, they work fine in Chrome/Edge.  They fail in Firefox.  I don't know why you are not seeing the same.  I am using Windows 11.  On what OS are you testing?  If it is Windows, I suggest you look again.  The screenshot you provided did not show the **local** example of the `textarea` and `div` elements in a scrolled state.  The comparison of these two elements in a scrolled state is necessary to see the issue.

Comment: No, after reviewing this, I misspoke, you are correct.

Answer (score -1):

It works for me in Firefox. Check the version you are using, [here you can find the allowance of this resource in firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment)

Hope this helped. :D